# Dynamic array push using $parse

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have three arrays and I want to push in array dynamically using $parse

For eg

```
$scope.image = [];
type = image;
var test = $parse(type);
test.assign($scope , push({id : 1}));
```

can I do something to make array push dynamic depending on type value or there is another way??

Comment: What is `type = image` supposed to accomplish…?

Comment: var type = "image"; it should be like this and type value can take another array value like type = "video or type = "gif"

Comment: If it's only a single string, `$scope[type].push(..)` will do just fine. `$parse` really only becomes interesting if you have more complex paths (e.g. `foo.bar.baz`).

Comment: Can you post what you have tried and not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to use `assign`; you will want to *get* the array, then manipulate it:

```
$scope.image = [];
var type = 'image';
var getter = $parse(type);
getter($scope).push({ id: 1 });
```

Comment: can you please give eg. how to do that